# sorting a list of dictionaries in a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a list of arrays which include a list of dictionaries in a text file. I have attempted to import json to use that inbuilt function however it didn't work with the format of the text file. Any suggestions on how to make it work. My other strategy involved manually filtering the values however I hit a snag since "bankroll" is mentioned in both public and private.

```
    bankroll=[]
with open("abc.txt", "r") as b:
    lines=b.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if "bankroll" in line:
        key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(':', 1)]
        bankroll.append[value]

[
{
    "private": {
        "bankroll": 1000,
        "last_bid": 0,
        "launching": false,
        "name": "abc",
        "tech": 0
    },
    "public": {
        "auction_round": 0,
        "game_stage": "start",
        "last_mining_payoff": 0,
        "last_winning_bid": 0,
        "last_winning_bidders": [],
        "last_winning_miner": "",
        "max_rounds": 201,
        "players": {
            "AggressiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "abc": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "PassiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "def": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "SpongeBob": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            }
        },
        "round": 0
    }
},
```

Above is an example of a singular element of many, in one of many arrays in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) should be straightforward:

```
>>> lines = '''
[
   {
    "private": {
        "bankroll": 1000,
        "last_bid": 0,
        "launching": false,
        "name": "abc",
        "tech": 0
    },
    "public": {
        "auction_round": 0,
        "game_stage": "start",
        "last_mining_payoff": 0,
        "last_winning_bid": 0,
        "last_winning_bidders": [],
        "last_winning_miner": "",
        "max_rounds": 201,
        "players": {
            "AggressiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "abc": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "PassiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "def": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "SpongeBob": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            }
        },
        "round": 0
    }
},
{
    "private": {
        "bankroll": 1000,
        "last_bid": 0,
        "launching": false,
        "name": "abc",
        "tech": 0
    },
    "public": {
        "auction_round": 0,
        "game_stage": "start",
        "last_mining_payoff": 0,
        "last_winning_bid": 0,
        "last_winning_bidders": [],
        "last_winning_miner": "",
        "max_rounds": 201,
        "players": {
            "AggressiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "abc": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "PassiveLauncher": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "def": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            },
            "SpongeBob": {
                "bankroll": 1000
            }
        },
        "round": 0
    }
}]
'''
>>>import json
>>>
>>> list_lines = json.loads(lines)
>>> 
>>> list_lines[0]
{'private': {'tech': 0, 'last_bid': 0, 'bankroll': 1000, 'name': 'abc', 'launching': False}, 'public': {'auction_round': 0, 'round': 0, 'max_rounds': 201, 'game_stage': 'start', 'last_mining_payoff': 0, 'last_winning_bid': 0, 'last_winning_miner': '', 'last_winning_bidders': [], 'players': {'PassiveLauncher': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'def': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'AggressiveLauncher': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'abc': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'SpongeBob': {'bankroll': 1000}}}}
>>> list_lines[1]
{'private': {'tech': 0, 'last_bid': 0, 'bankroll': 1000, 'name': 'abc', 'launching': False}, 'public': {'auction_round': 0, 'round': 0, 'max_rounds': 201, 'game_stage': 'start', 'last_mining_payoff': 0, 'last_winning_bid': 0, 'last_winning_miner': '', 'last_winning_bidders': [], 'players': {'PassiveLauncher': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'def': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'AggressiveLauncher': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'abc': {'bankroll': 1000}, 'SpongeBob': {'bankroll': 1000}}}}
>>> 
>>> list_lines[1]['private']['bankroll']
1000
```

In your case, you can directly de-serialize from your file object, using [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) :

```
>>> with open("abc.txt", "r") as b:
        lines = json.load(b)
```

Comment: I originally attempted this however I had an error. Specifically regarding the file having Extra data. My format of the file is slightly different to the your one. The file is basically the data in your question but repeated many times (by that I mean repeating the square brackets and everything inside).

Comment: So, it's a list of the example you posted?

Comment: Yh exactly. Thats an easier way to describe it

Comment: If your file has both json data and extra, then you will need to parse the required data with either `regex` or parsing tools